# Apache Require IP directive not working

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-authz-host

I have the following in my apache config file:

```
Define THUMBS_ROOT "//mysmbserver/website/thumbs"
Alias "/thumbs" "//mysmbserver/website/thumbs"
<Directory {THUMBS_ROOT}>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    <RequireAny>
        Require ip 66.54.56.34
        Require ip 159.101.84.4
    </RequireAny>
</Directory>
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
```

My apache version is Apache/2.4.29 (Win64). (Yes I realise this is an old version of Apache - I can't upgrade due to it being an appliance device)

Even those I've added RequireAny and RequireIP apache is ignoring this and allowing any IP to access the thumbs directory. I can't figure out why. Can anyone help me understand?

Further complicating matters I have a load balancer device sitting in front of apache so really what I need to be looking at is X-Forwarded-For not the source IP. I'm not sure offhand if I need to do anything for RequireIP to detect X-Forwarded-For?

Either way though its allowing access regardless of IP.

Edit: I've also tried:

```
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
Define THUMBS_ROOT "//mysmbserver/website/thumbs"
Alias "/thumbs" "//mysmbserver/website/thumbs"

SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "66.54.56.34" AllowIP1
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "159.101.84.4" AllowIP2

<Directory {THUMBS_ROOT}>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    <RequireAny>
        Require env AllowIP1
        Require env AllowIP2
    </RequireAny>
</Directory>
```

That doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory), the path in a `<Directory>` directive has to be a file system path, not an alias or variable. So I think your directive isn't having any effect, since there's no path `{THUMBS_ROOT}` in the file system.

Possible options:

- `<Directory //mysmbserver/website/thumbs>`. I don't know if this will work, but it might if Windows treats it as a valid file system path.
- `<Location /thumbs>`

Comment: Well now its actually blocking me! So that's part of the problem solved. Thanks! However its still not recognising X-Forwarded-For IPs. Any ideas on that?

Comment: The issue with x-forwarded-for has to do with my load balancer passing the wrong IP. Thanks for the help. I'm marking this as the answer. Thank you again!